# Клиент-серверная архитектура

Tags: android, книги, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте. Нужен сервер с базой данных и клиенты на пк и android с помощью которых будет выполняться работа с бд. Я пока не очень в этом разбираюсь. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать. Может какую-нибудь литературу (желательно русскую). Я так понимаю, делать все можно на java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста с чего начать.

почитать пару книг по java.

> Я так понимаю делать все можно на java?

на андроиде на java будет наиболее просто, на декстопе - в принципе тоже, если подойти правильно, то будет очень много общего кода.

> Нужен сервер с базой данных

на сервере хорошо сделать любую обертку на json/xml + REST. База наружу торчать не должна. [вариант 1](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody.html) и [вариант 2](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/). Я лично за json + REST. Но есть и любители xml. Можно и бинарные протоколы - protobuf.

> Может какую-нибудь литературу(желательно русскую)

[Брюс Эккель «Философия Java»](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19729271/) и [двухтомник Хорстманна и Корнелла](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3817476/).

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся недавно с такой проблемой. Я реализовал следующим образом: Android-> через JSON запросы -> PHP скрипт который непосредственно работает с MYSQL -> через JSON запрос возвращается результат -> Обрабатывается результат запроса. Как бы все.